# My latest Skype does not support group video call in hp ubuntu 16.04 lts?

Tags: skype

I have installed upgraded version of skype in my ubuntu 16.04 desktop. Nobody can't add me to the group call! I can only make group call to them, but i can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft unofficial stopped the support for Skype on Linux. I recommend switching to another VoiP Client like Teamspeak3 or Discord. You can also use Facebook's Messenger System.

Comment: There is a **tiny** downside with your suggestion: The OP's friends may use Skype.

Comment: This is unfortunate, but sadly a fact of life with commercial software.  I had this issue and "worked around it" (mightily unsatisfactorily) by running windows in VirtualBox and Skype from there.  This is half a solution, but unfortunately it's the best I could come up with :(